# connection error when a URL is down

Tags: python-3.x

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 88, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 78, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 245, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 309, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 88, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 78, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\Desktop\python scripts\link_monitor.py", line 50, in 
    mail_alert = validate_sites(sample_dict)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\Desktop\python scripts\link_monitor.py", line 20, in validate_sites
    for _site, _auth in sample_dict.items()]
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\Desktop\python scripts\link_monitor.py", line 20, in 
    for _site, _auth in sample_dict.items()]
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\Desktop\python scripts\link_monitor.py", line 14, in site_is_reachable
    response = requests.get(site_url, auth=authentication)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SD37561\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None))

> > > 

Comment: I have written a script to monitor the URL.. but it fails giving above error.. even after writing in try-except block

Comment: You need to provide more information and format your question more clearly.

Comment: I am traversing a dict as below  and getting connection error on first url in dict which is down...                                                                              for _site, _auth in sample_dict.items():  
    try :
        r = requests.get(_site, auth=_auth)
        if (str(r.status_code) != '200' ):
               print('Alert.....!!', _site, 'The URL get down')            
    except (ConnectionRefusedError , ConnectionError) as e :
            mail_alert = True

Comment: ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it                           requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None))
 raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None))

Comment: please help me resolve this error

Answer (score 1):

the error was catched by adding the except Exception for the dict traverse and now its getting handled and printing user friendly message